# How to get Datepicker from Calendar in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way to get datepicker from the calendar.

I'm trying this extension method but it returns null.

```
private void ChangeCalendarToToday(System.Windows.Controls.Calendar obj)
{
    var parent=obj.GetParentOfType<DatePicker>();
    obj.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
    obj.DisplayDate = DateTime.Now;
    obj.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Month;
}

public static T GetParentOfType<T>(this DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
{
        //get parent item
        DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

        //we've reached the end of the tree
        if (parentObject == null) return null;

        //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
        T parent = parentObject as T;
        if (parent != null)
            return parent;
        else
            return GetParentOfType<T>(parentObject);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the `parentObject`state  when you excute?

Comment: NonLogicalAdornerDecorator->Decorator->PopupRoot->null